# What is the aural equivalent of eye-witness?

Tags: single-word-requests

On the news this morning, the following was said:

> "Eye-witnesses say they heard two explosions"

Somehow this seems wrong, because the witnesses did not use their eyes, but their ears. Yet the phrase "ear-witness" sounds wrong.

Comment: Evidently, [*earwitness*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/earwitness) is a word, although I agree with you, it does sound a bit unfamiliar.

Comment: ***hearsay*** is not exactly the word. And it comes with negative connotations.

Comment: On the other hand, it need not be wrong at all. It is customary for the media to interview those at the site of the incident (literally, eye-witnesses alright), who may happen to have heard the explosions.

Comment: It kinda depends on how you define *eyewitness*. I go for Simon Jester's answer, but cf. the definition JeffSahol found.

Comment: @Kris "hearsay" isn't the "hearing" version of eyewitness. The word means information that you have heard from others rather than personally witnessing, or second-hand information. And despite the "hear" in the word, it doesn't have to be aural. If you read something in the gossip column of a newspaper and then repeated that it court, it would be called "hearsay evidence" even though you read it rather than hearing it.

Comment: @Jay I know. :-) Else it'd not have been a comment but an answer, right? And I did say it's not the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OED lists *ear-witness* as a valid word:

> A person who testifies, or is able to testify, to something on the evidence of his own hearing.

The earliest citation is dated 1597 and the word is not listed as obsolete or even archaic, but there are no recent citations, either.  Take that as you will...

Answer (score 4):

I would say there is no equivalent since the word eyewitness [("a person present at an event who can describe what happened")](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eyewitness) covers the concept already. Otherwise you might also need a word for a touch witness, or a smell witness.

Divorced of its literal meaning, that is. Not every gentleman is gentle, after all.

Comment: Surely it would be a "nose-witness", and...erm... a "finger-witness"?

Comment: Ah, you are correct, and thanks for not adding tongue-witness to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Only *witness* would suffice in case of aural evidence.

Comment: It's not "only witness" -- there's a great difference between 'witness' and 'eye-witness', the words are used in different contexts, though 'to witness' merely means 'to see'.

Comment: witness also means "to testify"

Answer (score 0):

Simon got it right.

It's not only a valid English word; it's the title of Elias Canetti's wonderful book *[Earwitness](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/earwitness.pdf)*, which gives 50 character sketches, all of which are ... well, odd, not to say insane; but all of them are also people you recognize as yourself, or someone you know ... sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers, *[earwitness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/earwitness)* is a highly suitable word.  However, in the context of

> X say they heard two explosions

I'd expect to find the plural of *[witness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/witness)* ("One who has a personal knowledge of something") rather than *earwitness* more commonly in place of X.  The word *[listener](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/listener)* ("Someone who listens") also works.  *[Auditor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/auditor#Noun)* apparently doesn't work in English, although in [Latin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/auditor#Noun_2) one of its meanings is "A hearer".